# What happens if the Jacobian matrix is not of full rank?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, implicit-function-theorem, jacobian

Suppose we have a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^{d+e} \to \mathbb{R}^{e}$, and let $\mathrm{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{d+e}$ is a point at which we have $f(\mathrm{x}_0) = 0$ and the Jacobian matrix of $f$ has a constant rank which is not full.

In the view of the Implicit Function Theorem, does this mean anything to $f^{-1}(\mathrm{0})$?
Are there extra conditions we can use to show that $f^{-1}(\mathrm{0})$ is/is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{d+e}$?

Comment: It's possible for $f^{-1}(0)$ to be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{d+e}$. Consider, for example, $d=e=1$ and the map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = x^2$. Then $f^{-1}(0)$ is the line defined by $x=0$, i.e., the $y$-axis, which is a smooth submanifold, even though at each point with $x=0$, the Jacobian has rank $0$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any extra criterion or test that decide whether $f^{-1}(\mathrm{0})$ is a smooth submanifold or not?